# Kivy: Gstreamer plugins won't work when trying to load remote mp4

Tags: python, kivy, gstreamer

Kivy Video widgets won't load remote MP4s.

For example,

`vid = Video("someremoteurl.mp4")`

I get the following output into the console:

```
python.exe:18172): GStreamer-WARNING **: 17:36:12.530: Failed to load plugin 'C:\dev\proj\venv\share\gstreamer\bin\gioopenssl.dll': 'C:\dev\proj\venv\share\gstreamer\bin\gioopenssl.dll': The specified module could not be found.

(python.exe:18172): GStreamer-WARNING **: 17:36:15.809: Failed to load plugin 'C:\dev\proj\venv\share\gstreamer\bin\gstrtmp.dll': 'C:\dev\proj\venv\share\gstreamer\bin\gstrtmp.dll': The specified module could not be found.

(python.exe:18172): GStreamer-WARNING **: 17:36:15.993: Failed to load plugin 'C:\dev\proj\venv\share\gstreamer\bin\librtmp-1.dll': 'C:\dev\proj\venv\share\gstreamer\bin\librtmp-1.dll': The specified module could not be found.
[WARNING] Deprecated property "<BooleanProperty name=play>" of object "<kivy.uix.video.Video object at 0x000001E2E9146820>" was accessed, it will be removed in a future version
```

Then, after that it outputs:

`[ERROR  ] [Image       ] Not found <someremoteurl.mp4>`

I have tried:

- Reinstalling `kivy-deps`
- Reinstall `gstreamer`

But so far, nothing seems to be working.